# Nosuchmethod:org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.diagnostics.DiagnosticSuppressor$Companion.getEP_NAME() from kotlin-compiler-embeddable.jar

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, lint

I wrote a custom lint plugin,when run the custom lint task,i found class `DiagnosticSuppressor$Companion` is from `kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.2.60.jar`,then it will report `NoSuchMethodError`,but gradle plugin lint task `class DiagnosticSuppressor$Companion` is from `kotlin-compiler-1.2.60.jar`.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.diagnostics.DiagnosticSuppressor$Companion.getEP_NAME()Lcom/intellij/openapi/extensions/ExtensionPointName;
        at com.android.tools.lint.LintCoreApplicationEnvironment.registerAppExtensionPoints(LintCoreApplicationEnvironment.java:145)
        at com.android.tools.lint.LintCoreApplicationEnvironment.createApplicationEnvironment(LintCoreApplicationEnvironment.java:94)
        at com.android.tools.lint.LintCoreApplicationEnvironment.get(LintCoreApplicationEnvironment.java:71)
        at com.android.tools.lint.LintCliClient.initializeProjects(LintCliClient.java:971)
        at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintClient.performInitializeProjects$lint_api(LintClient.kt:774)
        at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.kt:306)
        at com.android.tools.lint.LintCliClient.run(LintCliClient.java:179)
        at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleClient.run(LintGradleClient.java:254)
        at com.skateboard.hecatoncheires.checktools.IncrementLintGradleExecution.runLint(IncrementLintGradleExecution.java:250)
        at com.skateboard.hecatoncheires.checktools.IncrementLintGradleExecution.lintAllVariants(IncrementLintGradleExecution.java:391)
        at com.skateboard.hecatoncheires.checktools.IncrementLintGradleExecution.analyze(IncrementLintGradleExecution.java:85)
        ... 59 more
```